# How do I shuffle rows and colums in Android?

Tags: android, random, rows

I'm wanting to make a simple game to keep my kid occupied the coding below will be the main screen. What I'm hoping to do is get the imageview to show an animal and the table will contain the animal somewhere. I'd decided to use buttons that onclick will show the animals underneath it and for now I've labelled them with text from 1 - 25 so I can keep track of them for testing.

I have a button at the bottom (shuffle) How should I go about shuffling rows and columns when the shuffle button is pressed? For example button1 is set as the first button in row1 but it should move to another position in another row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:stretchColumns="*" >


       <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/ANIMAL" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:adjustViewBounds="true"></ImageView> 


          <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:text="3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button></TableRow>
      <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button07" android:text="7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button08" android:text="8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button09" android:text="9" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button10" android:text="10" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow03" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button11" android:text="11" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button12" android:text="12" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button13" android:text="13" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/Button14" android:text="14" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="15" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button15" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TableRow04">
                <Button android:text="16" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button16"></Button>
                <Button android:text="17" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button17"></Button>
                <Button android:text="18" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button18"></Button>
                <Button android:text="19" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button19"></Button>
                <Button android:text="20" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button20"></Button>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:id="@+id/tableRow05">
                <Button android:text="21" android:id="@+id/button21" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="22" android:id="@+id/button22" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="23" android:id="@+id/button23" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="24" android:id="@+id/button24" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:text="25" android:id="@+id/button25" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            </TableRow>  


        <Button android:id="@+id/mixbtn"  android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:clickable="true" android:text="Shuffle"></Button>
  </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I quess the easiest way I see is, instead of an xml layout, create an `ArrayList<Button> buttonsList` that you can add on `onCreate()` to the `TableLayout`. Then, upon `shuffleButton onClick()`, remove the buttons from the `TableLayout`, shuffle the array (`Collections.shuffle (buttonsList);`) and add them again.

I hope it makes sense to you